# On a node server, Lock down public image so only API server can download it?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication

I'm using an API ([printful](https://www.printful.com/docs/generator)) which requires providing a public URL in order to upload an image. I'm afraid of leaving these open to the public as people could then download the full resolution print files. Is there a way I could lock this down so normal users couldn't figure out the urls and type them in?

Using node/express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet might be to make the urls unguessable. You could use `crypto.randomBytes` to generate a random url. If it's long enough, it's statistically almost impossible for someone to guess it.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like that's a safe option. I found this article saying it's essentially what google does to make pictures private but publicly sharable: https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2015/07/googles_unguess.html